# Why do i have to use set_charset("utf8") even though everything is utf-8 encoded? (MySQLi-PHP)

Tags: php, utf-8, mysqli, character-encoding, collation

My table's collation is utf8_general_ci.

My pages are encoded with UTF-8 (without BOM).

Within my pages, my Equiv meta tag sets character set to utf8

My data has Turkish characters in it.

When i output them, it's not showing them as it should be but when i do `$db->set_charset("utf8");`, it works.

Why do i have to use `$db->set_charset("utf8");` even though everything is utf-8 encoded?

Comment: Unrelated to what you're asking, but are you setting the character set in `Content-type` in your HTTP response?

Comment: i use this: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf8" />`

Comment: Yes, but you should be setting that in the HTTP header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *data* is stored as UTF-8 in MySQL, but the PHP's client connection collation is not.  Which is why you have to use `set_charset` in PHP for the DB connection.

### Update

**php.ini**   : default_charset utf-8
**.htaccess** : AddDefaultCharset utf-8

Comment: Thanks, but can i change it through php.ini or anything like that?

Comment: i looked up to my mysql server's variables, and all collations and encodings are set to utf-8 so i know problem is not mysql server.

Thanks for the update: i checked up that php.ini variable's definition in PHP.net page (http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) and it is same as header('Content-type:utf-8') and `<meta content="charset=utf-8" />`

I also checked this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php and i could not find any mysql.default_charset variable so i think i will go with that "set_charset" function.

Thanks for reply, i appreciate it.

Comment: @Dada: I found `default_charset` under "Data Handling" on [the php.ini documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)