# data in mysql database is not in proper format

Tags: mysql, database, server, phpmyadmin, multilingual

I am trying to store data with multiple languages(mainly English, Hindi, Bengali, Punjabi). I am using UTF8mb4 charset and UTF8mb4_unicode_ci collation.I am able to insert and receive data from the database. on the HTML page, received data from database looks alike as I inserted it but, when I look at my database, data is not saved in the proper format.

[Output on html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHyfp.png)

[data in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlC53.png)

[Character set values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdmAB.png)

Comment: Is phpmyadmin set to display the correct character set?

Comment: @IbrahimShendy No. I haven't used that command.

Comment: @ANKIT See if it solves your problem ?

Comment: @IbrahimShendy I have used mysqli_set_charset($db,"utf8mb4"); and it works for me. But I there is any way where I make the change in configuration files and don't add this line.

Comment: To set the character set by default see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842980/a-permanent-way-of-doing-mysqli-set-charset

Answer (score 0):

Earlier i had the same issue:
if you set to UTF 8 it will work as you expected it happens when special characters are involved,

**Note:** make sure the data entered properly while inserting

```
mysqli_query($con,'SET NAMES utf8');
```

Comment: I have used
mysqli_set_charset($db,"utf8mb4");
after inserting this statement I am able to see the correct Chinese text in my database also.
Now my question is instead of adding this line if there is an alternate method where I can make a change in my configuration files to get rid of this problem.